# Selenium WebDriver All Parallel Tests Execute In A Single Window - TestNG - Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I am new to parallel execution and am trying to figure out why all 3 of my tests are trying to execute in a single window at the same time even though 3 separate windows are opened.

I have 3 nodes running all with Chrome and maxInstance and maxSession set to 1, so each node should get receive 1 class to run, which it appears they do as you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

This is what my test.xml file looks like:

```
<suite name="Round Trip Suite" parllel="tests" thread-count="3">

 <test name="Round Trip Matrix" preserve-order="true" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">

 <classes>
  <class name ="roundTripMatrix.VerifyNewOrder"/>
  <class name ="roundTripMatrix.DeclineAndAccept"/>
  <class name ="roundTripMatrix.OrderOwnership"/>
 </classes>

 </test>

</suite>
```

I am initializing the RemoteWebDriver in the @BeforeClass annotation like this:

```
if (browser.equals("Chrome"))
{
    String chromeDriver = "";
    if (os.equals("Windows"))
    {
        chromeDriver = userDir.replace(project, "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    }
    else
    {
        chromeDriver = userDir.replace(project, "drivers/chromedriver");
    }
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);

    if (useSeleniumGrid.equals("true"))
    {
        // Access Grid
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capability.setBrowserName("chrome");
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
    }
    else
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

} // end if for Chrome browser
```

**UPDATE:**

I have figured out the reason only one window was receiving the commands is because I wasn't using a threadlocal driver. My problem now is it fails at weird spots in all the windows, even though they were working while running individually previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your test.xml has error. Could you  try it:

```
<suite name="Round Trip Suite" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">
 <test name="Round Trip Matrix">
   <classes>
     <class name ="roundTripMatrix.VerifyNewOrder"/>
     <class name ="roundTripMatrix.DeclineAndAccept"/>
     <class name ="roundTripMatrix.OrderOwnership"/>
   </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

More information: [enter link description here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: So when I make that change, and I have 2 separate nodes with a max sessions and instances of 1 connected to the hub, the separate windows open, but only one window is receiving the commands and the others are just stagnant.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. You need Initialize your web driver for working in multithreaded environment.  Try this solution. [link] (http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/)